# Maintaining authentication using API and xhr

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, restful-authentication

I'm getting to grips with using an API to display the data on a page refresh. SO the first part is to authenticate using form based authentication. So I have this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function CallWebAPI()
 {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest(), data = 'username=admin&password=admin';
  request.open('POST', 'https://localIP:8443/api/users/_login', true)
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml")
  request.onreadystatechange = function() 
  {
         // D some business logics here if you receive return
    //if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    //}
  }
 
 request.send(data);
 }


 
</script>
</head>


<body>
<div>
<div id="response">
</div>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Call Web API" onclick="javascript:CallWebAPI();" />


</body>

</html>
```

So from the above, in the console browser I return a proper authentication message as thus:

SUCCESS

So I want to run another function to retrieve data now I'm logged in but it seems to reset back to 'unauthorised. All I did was create another function exactly the same except it was a GET rather than POST and added another button to test it. But it just kept returning 401: unauthorised. Am I doing it in the incorrect order or something?

I insert a second function like this:

```html
function getChannelStats()
 {
  var stats = new XMLHttpRequest();
  stats.open('GET', 'https://localIP:8443/api/channels/statistics?channelId=f237ae66-6c5b-4ffa-9396-0721eb575184', true)
  stats.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml")
  stats.onreadystatechange = function() 
  {
         // D some business logics here if you receive return
    //if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
        console.log(stats.responseText);
     //}
  }

  stats.send();
 }
 
 request.send(data);
 }
```

And add another button that class that function to get the responseText. I'm expecting an xml message with various numbers in it. But when I try to run it, it asks for me to authenticate - like it's not retaining it?

Comment: So you are calling the second endpoint where you have the `console.log` line?

Comment: I'll update the OP

Comment: So how is getChannelStats called?

Comment: <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Get stats" onclick="javascript:getChannelStats();" />